# MVC-Entity framework- data not commited to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I have the below code to perform CRUD operations in my MVC program.

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CustomerDal dal = new CustomerDal();

                dal.Customers.Add(obj);
                dal.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;//added this line to resolve issue but still no change
                dal.SaveChanges();
                return View("customer", obj);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("entercustomer",obj);
            }
```

and my customerdal class

```
   public class CustomerDal : DbContext
    {
        public CustomerDal(): base("CustomerDal")
    {
    }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("tbCustomer");
        }
        public DbSet<Customer>Customers { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

Customer class

```
public class Customer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerDal>
    {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}[0-9]{4,4}$")]
        [Key]
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    }
```

I am getting the below error when the program runs.

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

There is no record exists in the table. This is a newly created table.
when i inspect the element i can see all the items i tried before exist in the context but not updated to database. when i add new item which i didnt try before, the concurrency error will not occur. But the data will not update to database.

Note:Im using  MVC5

Comment: `dal.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;` this line shouldn't be there

Comment: @Ppp , i added that line after i got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I know what is your CustomerDal? Weird how the data is not updated to database. Is this a Code First application?

I suspect that you didn't include the connection string?

```
public class CustomerDal: DbContext
{
    public CustomerDal()
        : base("YourConnectionString")
    {
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: My Dal class and model updated in question. connection string is included already in the dal class.

Comment: No problem with that. Remove this line, `dal.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;` because this causes that exception. Rerun and see if it is still returning the same exception?

Comment: Yes. When i removed and rerun it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

soo... I've had a fair amount of practice with concurrency exceptions, there are a few primary error causes there:

1) when you add an entry, make sure your modelbuilder and your db have the same autoincrement value. if EF has autoincrement, but db not, EF won't pass the Id value in the insert statement, but will expect it back from the DBMS. if EF has no autoincrement, but db has, it will pass the ID in the created statement, but DBMS will not expect it. you can surpass this by wrapping your DB calls in a transaction, starting with IDENTITY INSERT (exact query depends on your provider, but most have this) and ending with Transaction.Commit();.

2) when you modify an entry, make sure the ID value AND all optimistic concurrency tokens are already present in the database (in one row). Otherwise EF will create an UPDATE statement, execute it, notice no rows were effected, and throw this error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i don't have anything similar to what you mentioned. the table and model builder have no auto-increment value.

Comment: do you PROVIDE a valid Id value then?

Comment: Yes. Its validated and returned true.